# Is there any sense in reusing game objects in XNA?

Tags: c#, object, xna, reusability

People often say I should reuse short-living objects in general, but I don't know it it's the case with XNA. There are items, particles and NPCs which are the most common game objects, should they be reused in some kind of pools or just deleted from update list and replaced with new instances? Will it matter performance wise?

Comment: Have you profiled your code to see if it matters?

Comment: I haven't tried it just yet, there's so much to rewrite just to find out, it was easier to ask if someone knows already.

Comment: typically the pooling is to save the init code and garbage collection that can sometimes slow you down when you've got tons of short lived sprites

Comment: By the way, tiny types that you have lots of - like particles - should probably be value types (`struct` not `class`). These don't really get "pooled" in the traditional sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pooling is very important in specific circumstances. That is, it is nearly always beneficial in situations where you have heavy creation and disposal of common objects, like bullets or voxel instances.

The Garbage Collector is nice, but it is not always your friend. If you build a game like I did which uses thousands of cubes to render terrain and objects, you will notice this quickly (though it took us several weeks to realize it was indeed the GC which caused our slowdowns). As programmers in managed language, we were used to simply dereferencing an object and having it be magically whisked away by the GC. The fact was, though, that when those objects get into the thousands, the GC works overtime. You'll notice significant slowdown every minute or so, depending.

So, instead of constantly instantiating and dereferencing your common objects, it is far less stressful on the GC to use a static, stable-sized pool of objects.

- static: All of the objects are instantiated at once and are not dereferenced at runtime to be picked up by the GC
- stable-sized: the number of object instances in the pool does not change very often (prevents instantiating bogging down performance)

The reason behind all this is that the GC, in a basic sense, has to cleanup after you for all the references contained in each and every object you dereference during your game. So, if your block has a reference to an adjacent block, it's got to check to see if that was the only reference to that other block was the only one, because if so, that other block is now dereferenced too by proxy (again, very simplistic view, but this is how I learned it).

By creating a pool and simply reusing instances instead of discarding them, you never trigger this behavior from the GC when you're done with one of these objects, so you don't have to worry about it doing heavy checks on thousands or hundreds of objects as you create and destroy them willy-nilly.

I'd say, basically, you'll know when you need pooling. You'll experience unexplained slowdowns periodically which don't seem to be tied to the actions you're performing in the game. This is the GC doing cleanup behind the scenes for you.

Comment: Do you know how I can measure the GC work time like surrounding my own methods with Stopwatch?

Comment: This could help you: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee851764.aspx I'm afraid it was my partner who did the initial profiling to identify that the GC was an issue, and he's not around for me to ask at the moment what he used.

Answer (score 3):

In my experience, it depends on if it is an xbox 360 project.  The xbox 360 will not be able to process as much as a pc normally can these days.  This is especially the case when garbage collection kicks in.

http://zfs.fzi.de/attachments/article/160/XNA_Optimization.pdf

Notice one of the first "things to consider" in this pdf is xbox 360 garbage collection.  The xbox 360 garbage collection time will increase linearly with every object that is created.